# How to query for newly created property in NDB?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I had NDB class before and added new property `receive_news` just now:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    '''
    Index
        Key: user_id
    '''
    lang = ndb.StringProperty(required=None, indexed=True)
    receive_news = ndb.BooleanProperty(required=None, indexed=True)
```

I would like to get list of users, who would like to receive my news (all users currently). I tried the following options:

```
keys = User.query(User.receive_news != True).fetch(keys_only=True)
keys = User.query(User.receive_news == None).fetch(keys_only=True)
```

both returns 0. How should I work properly with this new property?

Answer (score 0):

Datastore indexes are only updated when entities are being written to the datastore, so only entities written **after the new index was created** will be added to it.

To have the pre-existing entities added to the index (so that they can be found by the query) you'll have to get and then re-write them. Maybe using something along these lines (you'll have to split it in separate requests/tasks if they are too many)

```
keys = []
for user in ndb.get_multi(User.query().fetch(keys_only=True)):
    if  user.receive_news is None:
        user.receive_news = True
        keys.append(user.key)
ndb.put_multi(keys)
```