# what's the cost for google datastore create/delete index

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an existing table of google datastore, I want only to update its index.
My question is: When I create/delete index, if it is free (not datastore storage cost, I mean only the action of create/delete index itselt)?
I don't find about this in their tarif page  https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indexing operations themselves are free - normally they're absorbed in the entity write operation costs. But the storage space used for the indexes contribute is considered in the overall storage costs (see the `Summary` in the [Datastore Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/stats)).

You shouldn't normally need to update indexes (they're automatically updated at entity writes) unless:

- you add/delete composite indexes (you can't modify existing composite indexes, you can only add new ones and [cleanup](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig#Datastore_Deleting_unused_indexes) the ones no longer used)
- you change properties from non-indexed to indexed or viceversa - note that you'd need to re-write the existing entities to be included into/excluded from the indexes (with associated write ops costs), see [How to query for newly created property in NDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399187/how-to-query-for-newly-created-property-in-ndb/45400992#45400992)

Comment: thx! But "the storage space used for the indexes contribute is considered in the overall storage costs" - I don't think so, datastore pricing page shows that $0.18 /GB/Month for stored data, and storage pricing page shows that $0,026 /GB/Month.

Comment: Sorry, by storage I meant datastore storage, not GCS. Both entities and indexes go in there.

Comment: ha, ok :D In fact, "The indexing operations themselves are free" your first sentence has been exactly the answer I'm looking for. Because in my project, the cost of datastore storage has been too too too expensive! I'd like to remove a large volume of index, just to verify it is FREE.